# Tips for creating “Context Free Grammar”

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I am new to CFG's, Can someone give me tips in creating CFG that generates some language

For example

$L =\{ w v w^R \mid v,w\in \{a,b\}^*\wedge|v| \text{ is even } \}$, where  $w^R$ is the reverse of
     string $w$.

I'm having trouble understanding the language .. I want to build DFA to convert it

Comment: Welcome to SE Computer Science. What is your idea of the language, even if you have trouble understanding it? What can a DFA have to do with your problem?

Comment: I would build a DFA to convert it to CFG .. but the language not clear fo me

Comment: use the search engine to find similar questions in this site, and get some intuition. See, for example, [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9831/context-free-grammar-for-language-l)

Comment: also check our reference questions, and in particular [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free)

Comment: I think you are confusing DFA (Deterministic Finite Automaton) with PDA (Push-Down Automaton)

Comment: Converting a PDA to a CFG is not particularly simple, and in this case it's not hard to construct a CFG directly, so that's a better option. Construction a PDA is also not too difficult, so you can take that as an additional exercise.

Comment: FWIW, DFA's *can*, of course, be converted to CFGs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmmm.

Let me note that in fact $L =\{ w v w^R \mid v,w\in \{a,b\}^*\wedge|v| \text{ is even } \}$ equals $\{ v  \mid v \in \{a,b\}^*\wedge|v| \text{ is even } \}$.

Al strings in $L$ are of even length, and conversely all strings of even length can be otained by taking $w=\varepsilon$.

That should help.

Comment: I wonder whether this was expected !

Comment: @babou That is a good question. Perhaps the DFA confusion is related to this?

Comment: Cute! It might help the OP even more if you included a sentence of explanation. (Too bad I can't upvote twice.)

Comment: It is really a great psychological example of the way we work, and what may block us. Science is largely a question of looking at thing the right way. Hence the importance of conceptualization and notation. But in such a simple example ... Great for teaching.

Comment: I think this question should not be closed. The answer is indeed too cute. What do you think?  cc @RickDecker

Comment: Yes, I didn't see it -- subtle problem -- I was too hasty to answer. Looks line ww^R, but adding the even length string in the middle changes everything since ww^R is always even and you can always let w = empty string.

Comment: @babou. I agree that this question shouldn't be closed, especially in light of the fact that nothing in the reference question comes close to this answer.

Comment: @RickDecker if Hendrick Jan agrees, we can take this to chat, I am afraid that is the only effective way.

Comment: There's a very similar question [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/).

Comment: Indeed, the question Rick links is much closer to a reason for closing as duplicate than the canned how-to-context-free question.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1. Construct a non-terminal $V$ and appropriate productions so that $V$ generates all strings of even length.
2. Create productions so that your starting symbol $S$ generates $wVw^R$ for all $w$. To accomplish that, modify a grammar for $ww^R$.